# Elasticsearch authorization failed with shield

Tags: elasticsearch, installshield, kibana-4

If I run kibana I can see this error

**log   [11:15:40.772] [info][status][plugin:kibana] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.804] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [11:15:40.821] [info][status][plugin:kbn_vislib_vis_types] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.826] [info][status][plugin:markdown_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.831] [info][status][plugin:metric_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.837] [info][status][plugin:spyModes] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.842] [info][status][plugin:statusPage] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.847] [info][status][plugin:table_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [11:15:40.866] [info][listening] Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
  log   [11:15:40.881] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to red - Authentication Exception**

```
Environment 2.1.1
shield 2.1
kibana 4.3.0
```

After some google search I found out this

Elasticsearch works with standard HTTP basic authentication headers to identify the requester. Since Elasticsearch is stateless, this header must be sent with every request:

Authorization: Basic

The  is computed as base64(USERNAME:PASSWORD)

My question is from which path or file i needs to set this authorization: Basic